# How to install bcrypt to Openshift nodejs server

Tags: node.js, openshift, bcrypt

I using openshift Nodejs(Latest) cartrige, so when I trying to use bcrypt-nodejs module it has error "octal literals are not allowed in strict mode". So I switched to bcrypt module but was unable to install it as it needs python.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this library? https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs